# Initialise and pull terraform public modules using GitHub SSH private key

Tags: github, ssh, gitlab, terraform

Context:
I have gitlab runners which are executing `terraform init` command which is pulling all necessary terraform modules. Recently, I started hitting github throttling issues (60 calls to github api per hour). So I am trying to reconfigure my pipeline so it uses Github user's private key.

Currently, I have the following in my pipeline but it still doesn't seem to work and private key isn't used to pull the terraform modules.

```
- GITHUB_SECRET=$(aws --region ${REGION} ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /github/umotifdev --with-decryption --query 'Parameters[*].{Name:Name,Value:Value}' --output json);
- PRIVATE_KEY=$(echo "${GITHUB_SECRET}" | jq -r '.[] | select(.Name == "/github/umotifdev/private_key").Value' | base64 -d);
- PUBLIC_KEY=$(echo "${GITHUB_SECRET}" | jq -r '.[] | select(.Name == "/github/umotifdev/public_key").Value' | base64 -d);
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh;
- echo "${PRIVATE_KEY}" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa;
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa;
- eval $(ssh-agent -s);
- ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa;
- ssh-keyscan -H 'github.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts;
- ssh-keyscan github.com | sort -u - ~/.ssh/known_hosts -o ~/.ssh/known_host;
- echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config;
- echo ${PUBLIC_KEY} >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The error I am seeing in my pipeline is something like (which is basically throttling from github):

```
Error: Failed to download module
Could not download module "vpc" (vpc.tf:17) source code from
"https://api.github.com/repos/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/tarball/v2.21.0//*?archive=tar.gz":
bad response code: 403.
```

Anyone can advise how to resolve an issue where private key isn't used to pull terraform modules?

Comment: I find it curious that you need to download Terraform modules over sixty times per hour. Are you releasing a new version of your modules multiples times per day? Are you always retrieving the latest git commit of a module instead of releasing versions? Are you not retaining modules downloaded from the previous job? Have you tried a shared plugins directory?

Comment: I have multiple small modules such as vpc flow logs, Kms, ecs task definition etc. With multiple projects using them pipelines executed by girl are runners are pulling them quite often. And yes we making more than 60 pull request per hour. At the moment I am not retaining these modules. Could you provide a link to shared plugins directory info?